# React + Less + customize-cra

Tags: reactjs, less, customize-cra

I have two files with variables - src/lessVariables/Blue.less and src/lessVariables/Neutral.less

I try to import variables from files

```
@import "./src/lessVariables/Blue.less"
.Container { background: @blue500 }
```

And I have **"Invalid dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this module. All reported dependencies need to be absolute paths"** warning in terminal

How to fix this?

Comment: in config-override I have
addLessLoader({
        lessLoaderOptions: {
            lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
            }
        }
    })

Comment: I have the same problem when I use absolute path of the import
@import "src/lessVariables/Blue.less"